# KarmaJS throws readonly error in afterAll method

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I have a project that contains:

- Angular 1.6.10
- Jasmine 3.1.0
- PhantomJS 2.2.1
- Karma 2.0.2

I'm creating an unit test for the following class:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Core').controller('MainController', function() {

  var $this = {
    calculateBirthYear: function(age) {
      return (2018 - age);
    }
  };
  return $this;
});
```

The test js:

```
describe('Testing AngularJS Test Suite', function() {

  var MainController;

  beforeEach(module('Core'));
  beforeEach(inject( function ($controller) {
        MainController = $controller('MainController');
  }));


  it('should sum correctly the birth date', function() {
      console.log('Birth: %o',MainController.calculateBirthYear(18));
      expect(MainController.calculateBirthYear(18)).toBe(2000);
  });

});
```

When I look the logs, it shows that it is calculating but with an error that I've no idea how to deal.

```
LOG: 'Birth: %o', 2000
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property."
  }
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, if anybody can throw some solution it would be very helpful.

Comment: same here, but with Jasmine 2.99.1 :( It seems to happen when I'm testing some async behaviour with Observables mocked by MockNgRedux